# How to make this code show capital first letters using ucfirst?

Tags: php

how do I include `ucfirst` into this code:

```
<?php echo $this -> title ?>
```

I want to make all title page show a capital letter for the first character.

**Example** *hello* would become *Hello*

Comment: A simple search will show you how to do it

Comment: I don't know what you mean sorry. I've only been trying to code for the last week very new to this it's a real blur.

Comment: @user2891289: What exactly don't you understand? Did you try searching online before asking here? A simple search for [*make first letter capital php*](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+first+letter+capital+php) would have given you the right answer (with examples).

Comment: I wish the StackOverflow community was more welcoming of new users.

Comment: @Jason, I agree that the community's _tone_ could frequently be kinder. But if we were to _permit_ questions like this one, then really we'd have to drop the whole expectation that any user did any web-searching prior to posting, and the site would take a huge drop in quality. The PHP tag is, sadly, full of un-researched questions as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php echo ucfirst($this->title); ?>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! And I meant to say 'ucwords' but I just replaced 'ucfirst' with it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it with PHP. This is a presentational task and should be done using CSS:

```
<span style="text-transform:capitalize"><?php echo $this->title; ?></span>
```

For brevity I've used an inline style declaration, a class would be better in *real-life*.

Comment: May i know why did you vote to close the question and answered the question as well ? O.o

Comment: They only want the first letter capital.

Comment: Sorry have changed it

Comment: Maybe people read my comment.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Good job! Why I can't answer a question - help a guy - but keeping SO clean at the same time? What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: `text-transform:capitalize` Will transform ALL letters of the word, not just the first.

Comment: @relentless That's wrong! It will uppercase the first char only.

Comment: Oh, damn, sorry. I just looked it up again. I was wrong. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran And you called me once *a hater*! (although I upvoted you that time) LOL :D

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but I got one as well. Guess @Shankar Damodaran campaign won.